# how to place multiple div side by side with a unique layout

Tags: css

I am trying to place 7 divs side by side but with a bit of uniqueness.
You can take a look at what I have done so far through the link [HERE](http://www.hydrocell.co/test3.html) and view page source.

I want the Center div's width to fill the space between the **Left Middle** and **Right Middle** div irrespective of how far one drags the browser form to the left or right. At the moment the center div has white spaces left and right of it.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Do you have a reason for wrapping the two left and the two right divs in another div? By my mind, two float:left; would float next to one another?

Comment: I was experimenting with the floats but then I couldnt get the specific divs to stretch with the form. The way I have it is how I have been making prgress towards my goal. If you have any suggestions please share

Comment: Unfortunately not, hence the comment instead of an answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with `<table>`. If you are pretending to use div-based structure, then you can simulate divs behaviour by using `display:table` etc...

here is HTML:

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%;">
  <div style="display:table-row">

    <div style="display:table-cell;width:100px;background:blue;">Left Fixed</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;width:auto;background:green;">Left Stretch</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;width:120px;background:yellow;">Left Middle</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;width:auto;background:#999;">Center</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;width:120px;background:yellow;">Right Middle</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;width:auto;background:green;">Right Stretch</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;width:100px;background:blue;">Right Fixed</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: [demo link](http://jsbin.com/uwuyax/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`.

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/8Gu4uApo)***

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">first</div>
   <div class="child2">first2</div>
   <div class="child3">first3</div>
   <div class="child4">first4</div>
   <div class="child5">first5</div>
 <div class="child6">first6</div>
   <div class="child7">first7</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  margin:0 auto;
  background:red;
  font-size:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.child, .child1, .child2, .child3, .child4, .child5, .child6, .child7{
display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:100px;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:12px;
}
.child{
background:green;
}
.child2{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.child3{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.child4{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.child5{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.child6{
background:rgba(45,234,0,0.9);
}
.child7{
background:rgba(232,0,222,0.9);
}
```

***[LIve demo](http://tinkerbin.com/8Gu4uApo)***

Answer (score 0):

Your left div has a width of 45%; your right div similarly. But the middle div has a width of 8%, so there's 2% left over.

If you make the centre div have a width of 10%, the gaps disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I would also like the center div to be a fixed width with no white spaces when the browser form is resized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
            <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 10%; margin-top: 0px; background-color: #999">
                Center</div>
        </div>
```

since you had the two divs width's add up to 90% and the center div as 8%, fix this and the center this fills up the center

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without any problem using HTML `<table>`. Or if you want to have it table-less, by using only div-based structure, then you can simulate table's behavior with display as `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell` in your CSS

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4rLa8/)*** is a Live Demo.

Comment: or if you want to have it table-less, by using only div-based structure, then you can simulate div's behaviour with `display` - `table, table-row, table-cell` etc...

Comment: that's true @aspirinemaga . I am adding this to my answer.